# Lambda creation Error creating application: You are not authorized to perform: serverlessrepo:GetApplication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Can anyone help me with any solution to solve this error while creating  an AWS Lambda application from IAM user account:

> Error creating application: You are not authorized to perform: serverlessrepo:GetApplication.

My permissions are:

[image: Permissions for IAM user]

Comment: @NickMartin nice one, I've bookmarked the nocode page to use in the future!

Answer (score 2):

In IAM console, firstly go into Policy to create policy and choose the service name `Serverless Application Repository`. And config actions and resources for your requirement (by default, the selected option of `Resources` is a specific repository).

[image]

After created, go to `User` in IAM console and attach the new policy for this user.

Now you should be able to `perform: serverlessrepo:GetApplication`. If you found that refreshing page does not take effect, please log out and log in again to apply the policy.

Answer (score 1):

As the exception says

> You are not authorized to perform: serverlessrepo:GetApplication

This means that your IAM user, or the role assumed by the deployment process, does not have an `Allow` effect for the `serverlessrepo:GetApplication` action.

To resolve this add a policy with an `Allow` effect for `serverlessrepo:GetApplication` to your IAM user, or the role being assumed by the deployment function.